# pygame sprite group draw not drawing all sprites

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote a program that creates 4 sprites as rectangles that bounce around within the pygame surface.  The position is updated in the update procedure for the sprite.  When I run the program, only 1-3 of the rectangles appear and which rectangles appear is random.  I added a print statement and I can see each sprite is being updated.

Here is the code:

```
# import pygame library so we can use it!
import pygame
import random
import mygame_colors

# run initialization code on the library
pygame.init()

# setup display dimensions
display_width = 1200
display_height = 600
FPS = 30

gameSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Window Caption!')
colors = (mygame_colors.RED,mygame_colors.GREEN,mygame_colors.WHITE,mygame_colors.BLUE)

# game code that needs to run only once

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, number):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10*(number+1), 10))
        self.number = number
        # self.color = (random.randint(100,255),random.randint(100,255),random.randint(100,255))
        self.color = colors[x]
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (random.randint(0,display_width), random.randint(0,display_width))
        self.x_speed = random.randint(-30,30)
        if self.x_speed == 0:
            self.x_speed += 1
        self.y_speed = random.randint(-30,30)
        if self.y_speed == 0:
            self.y_speed += 1
    def update(self,*args):
        super().update(self,*args)
        self.rect.x += self.x_speed
        self.rect.y += self.y_speed
        x,y = self.rect.center
        if x > display_width or x < 0:
            self.x_speed *= -1
        if y > display_height or y < 0:
            self.y_speed *= -1
        print ("%s %s: %s,%s,%s"%(self.number,self.color,self.rect.x,self.rect.y,self.image))


# create game clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# create a sprite group to keep track of sprites
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

for x in range(4):
   player = Enemy(x)
   all_sprites.add(player)

# fill entire screen with color
gameSurface.fill(mygame_colors.BLACK)

# main game loop
running = True  # when running is True game loop will run
while running == True:
    # get input events and respond to them
    # if event is .QUIT
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    clock.tick(FPS)

    # game code that repeats every frame
    # clear display (redraw background)
    gameSurface.fill(mygame_colors.BLACK)


    # update
    all_sprites.update()    # draw all sprites
    all_sprites.draw(gameSurface)

    # pygame.draw.rect(gameSurface, r_color, [rectX, rectY, 25, 25])
    # pygame.draw.circle(gameSurface,r_color,(int(rectX),int(rectY)),25)
    # gameSurface.blit(image1, [rectX, rectY])


    # update and redraw entire screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # pygame.display.update()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(pygameColors.GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (display_width / 2, display_height / 2)
```

Comment: Here is the code for mygame_colors.py:
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GRAY = (235, 235, 235)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (65, 231, 255)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the rectangles are randomly out of the window, because the rectangles are place in the area `display_width` * `display_width` rather than `display_width` *  `display_height`:

Change the placement of the rectangles to solve the issue:

<s>`self.rect.center = (random.randint(0,display_width), random.randint(0,display_width))`</s> 
`self.rect.center = (random.randint(0,display_width), random.randint(0,display_height))`